# How to treat a shelved CL in Perforce as a patch?

Tags: perforce

Suppose I created a shelved change list (CL) numbered `2903395` on Monday. The change was never submitted, but other modifications were, and they touched the files of my CL.

On Tuesday, I want to apply the shelved CL and submit it:

```
p4 unshelve -s 2903395
```

But here's what happens: the changes to my file made by others are now discarded and my original change is applied.
That's not what I want: I want my change to be applied on top of the changes made by others. How can I do that?

I'm coming from Git, so I'm thinking in terms of doing a `git format-patch` on Monday and `git am` on Tuesday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to mess around with patching; Perforce handles this automatically!  Do:

```
p4 unshelve -s 2903395
p4 sync
p4 resolve -am
```

When you `p4 unshelve` the files are restored to the state they were in when you `p4 shelve`d, including the "have revision" that tracks which depot revision they were based on -- only when you `p4 sync` does this get updated to reflect the newly submitted revisions, and then `p4 resolve` merges the changes in.

Comment: And if you're doing this to do the equivalent of "rebasing" your shelf to the current head of main, you can either (a) replace your current shelf with the new files after sync'ing and resolve'ing, or (b) create a new shelf with the new files at that point. It's mostly a matter of taste, although each shelf does consume some server resources.